# How do I cook frozen fish in microwave?

Tags: baking, fish

I have no baking oven. How can I cook frozen fish in a microwave oven, and how long will it take to be ready?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell when fish is done baking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15239/how-to-tell-when-fish-is-done-baking)

Comment: what kind of fish? full or filet ? what does google say about it ?

Comment: https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/salmon-fillet-en-papillote-with-julienne-vegetable-recipe-1914616.amp

Comment: I don't think that is a duplicate. However, I do think it's too broad -- ushna, could you please [edit] to include details about what sort of fish, what preparation (sauce spices etc) you have in mind, and so on?

Comment: @Erica I flagged it prior to the edit, when it was in fact a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently cook fish in the microwave, as I'm the only one who eats it in my house. Thaw filet in cold water and place on microwave safe dish.  I turn fish over halfway through cooking.  The kind of fish and the thickness will determine time.  I recommend using partial power or your fish will be rubbery.  I have a 1200 watt microwave and the following is just a guideline.
From completely thawed:

Salmon filet @2" thick - about 2 minutes each side at 70%
White fish or Tilapia filet (these are very thin @ 1/4") 1 minute on each side at 80%.

Please be aware that this is just from my personal experience.